# Auctions in Boost ASIO

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm implementing an auctioning system in C++ with Boost.Asio. There is a single centralized auctioneer (the server) and some connecting bidders (the clients). I am implementing this in an asynchronous fashion, and I have implemented the basic communication between the bidder and auctioneer (register, ping, get client list). The skeletal code for the auctioneer would look like follows:

```
class talkToBidder : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<talkToBidder>
{
// Code for sending and receiving messages, which works fine
};

void on_round_end()
{
  // Choose the best bid and message the winner
  
  if (!itemList.empty())
    timer_reset();
}

void timer_reset()
{
  // Send the item information to the bidders

  // When the round ends, call on_round_end()
  auction_timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::millisec(ROUND_TIME));
  auction_timer.async_wait(boost::bind(on_round_end));
}

void handle_accept(...)
{
  // Create new bidder...

  acceptor.async_accept(bidder->sock(),boost::bind(handle_accept,bidder,_1));
}


int main()
{
  // Create new bidder and handle accepting it
  talkToBidder::ptr bidder = talkToBidder::new_();
  acceptor.async_accept(bidder->sock(),boost::bind(handle_accept,bidder,_1));

  service.run();
}
```

My issue is, I need to wait for at least one bidder to connect before I can start the auction, so I cannot simply call `timer_reset()` before I use service.run(). What is the Boost.Asio way to go about doing this?

Comment: It's a bit tricky to guess what this code is supposed to do? This is a multi-round simultaneous-bid auction? And the timer is a per-round timer? If so, is your problem with the first round, or with all rounds?

Comment: Sorry if it isn't clear, I will add any details needed. The auction is a multi-round blind auction. Every round, the auctioneer sends the details of an item to the registered bidders, and the bidders respond with their bids. The round ends after a certain amount of time, and the auctioneer declares the highest bidder the winner (by sending it a message). This continues till all the items have been auctioned. My issue is with the first round (which will spawn successive rounds). How can I make it wait on a condition (at least one bidder) asynchronously?

Comment: Ok, you're using a somewhat unusual terminology. The Nobel Price for Economy was recently awarded for theories about multi-round auctions. Those are auctions in which there are multiple rounds for the same item(s), with generally the same bidders. It seems that you have one bidding round per item? But can bidders join and leave between items? That means the `bidders==0` case can also happen between items/rounds.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to implement [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4209606). I tried to explain the use case without going into the exact terminology from the paper since it would be more clear, but it seems I've failed :). You're right, that is a situation that could happen, but I thought that if I get the idea behind starting it, I could fix any other issues. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In asynchronous protocol design, it helps to draw Message Sequence Diagrams. [Do include your timers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/153560/how-to-visualize-timer-functionality-in-sequence-diagram).

The code now becomes trivial. You start your timer when the message arrives that should start your timer. Yes, this is shifting the problem a bit forwards. The real point here is that it's not a Boost Asio coding problem. In your case, that particular message appears to be the login of the first bidder, implemented as a TCP connect (`SYN/ACK`) which maps to `handle_accept` in your code.

Comment: I was attempting to shoehorn some extra code into pre-existing code and definitely thought in the wrong direction with it, it is quite trivial. Thanks for you help!